# puppylinux: acpitool -s in .sh file

Tags: shell, acpi, puppy-linux

I am using puppylinux (xenialpup 64 bit). In order to put it to sleep mode, I run "acpitool -s" in cli. It works fine.

But if I put it in a file, save it as .sh file, then mark it as executable, and then double-click to execute it. It makes the system sleep for just a moment and turns on immediately. I didn't understand what is missing / going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting answer to my own Q so that it might be useful to someone else also.

```
acpitool -s
read
```

This should go into a .sh file.
Mark this file as executable.
Run it.
And it does the trick.